# how can i Integration all texts from a column in a form to a textBox Microsoft Access VBA ms-access

Tags: vba, ms-access, integration

how can i Integration all texts from a column in a form to a textBox ?

this code can add all text **from table** to textbox in form

```
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("names")
For i = 1 To rs.RecordCount

text1.SetFocus
text1.Text = text1.Text & " " & rs(1)

rs.MoveNext

Next i
```

is it any way to add all text **from Fields in form** in to textbox in same form?

Comment: please rephrase your question. It is impossible to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your sub com1_Click with following block. Hope this helps . . .

```
Private Sub com1_Click()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strNames As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    ' Following line gets the query of the form
    strSQL = Me.RecordSource
    ' Alternatively, you can replace this line with your own select query
    ' For eg.
    ' strSQL = "Select * from Table1 Where [_ID] In (1,2)"


    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    strNames = ""

    'Following loop is for going through all the records
    While Not rs.EOF
        'Following line is for collecting values of Name1 Field of your table
        strNames = strNames & " " & rs("Name1")
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend

    ' Populating the textbox with values collected from your table
    text3 = Trim(strNames)

    ' Final cleanup
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the controls in the form and put it in a string variable (or a textbox).

```
Dim cControl As Control
Dim sNames As String
sNames = ""
For Each cControl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(cControl) = "TextBox" Then
        sNames = sNames + " " + cControl
    End If
Next cControl
```

Comment: sir Romi first let me say thanks to help and  tray to workout code but i did not successful ,, so i hop to help me again, i Attach the example to modify it.
http://www.mediafire.com/?4d3kykcnbetvcvy